# can one drawable instance be used on multiple imageView?

Tags: android, caching, android-imageview, android-drawable

in a listview, for each item it needs to show some image(drawable) for different item name. If the name are same they show same image. The drawable is specific and cost some time to make it (need remote resource).
So thought maybe cache the drawable and only build new one if it has not been cached.
saw some article "ANDROID DRAWABLE INSTANCES – DON’T SHARE THEM!"
http://loseyourmarbles.co/2013/09/android-drawable-instances-dont-share/,

and here also need to animate the drawable. But test seems not seeing bad behavior (maybe not tested enough)?

So anyone has had similar requirement and experienced whether one drawable instance could be used on multiple ImageView? Is this approach right way to speed up the listview?

Or can one drawable instance be used on multiple imageView?

```
HashMap<String, Drawable> mNameToDrawnable = new HashMap<>();

public Drawable getDrawable(Context context, String displayName){

    Drawable cachedD = mNameToDrawnable.get(displayName);
    if (cachedD != null) {
        return cachedD;
    }

    Drawnable d = makeDrawable(displayName);  //new Drawable(context.getResources());, etc ……
    d.setDecodeDimensions(100, 100);

    mNameToDrawnable.put(displayName, d);

    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the cached drawable in your listview and you're worried about some issues with it you might want to call mutate() on your drawable. This might give you a better understanding : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html?m=1

Comment: thanks Piotr! The only difference in the article it mentioned that the list has new drawable instance for each list item. Not sure if there is anything to worry if multiple items sharing same drawable instance.

Comment: Hmmm I guess it really depends on your case. If you do not modify the drawable in any way it might work. I'd check it on various OS versions though just  to be sure.